# Pronunciation of зелёный

Tags: произношение

I have listened to it about a thousand times and i still cannot get it , зелёный

Is it like this zyelyoный? I can say the end but is the beginning right, thank you

Comment: it would be more fruitful if you recorded your own pronunciation and posted a link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but avoid the hard connection in the **zye** and **lyo**, the phoneme **[y]** should not create a barrier between the adjacent sounds, instead it must smoothly connect them so the 1st flows into the 3d.

Also mind you that due to reduction in an unstressed position **зе-** should be pronounced as **зи-**

So I would transcribe them as **zee** and **lio** or better yet, with the view of the English pronunciation as **leo** -> **zeeleoniy**